# Why does this cause an Overfull hbox?

Tags: tables

On the following MWE, I am just trying to do an array, the width of which is equal to the textwidth, basically I want my array to be as large as the document allows it to. That's what I am doing in my actual report so I think it's quite representative.

Here is my MWE :

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{llr}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth}}{Item} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2}
Animal    & Description & Price (\$) \\
\midrule
Gnat      & per gram    & 13.65      \\
          & each        & 0.01       \\
Gnu       & stuffed     & 92.50      \\
Emu       & stuffed     & 33.33      \\
Armadillo & frozen      & 8.99       \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Yet, I am getting an overfull `\hbox` of 77.5pt too wide. What's the explanation behind this ?

Comment: There's `2\tabcolsep` added. Try `p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}`. Or better `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X}...\end{tabularx}` from `\usepackage{tabularx}`. As well, please put `\noindent` in front of the table since the line indentation eats some space.

Comment: (i'm not in a position to test, so this id off the top of my head.)  you are giving the width of the full page for only the first two columns, so the width will be over by the width of the last column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forcing the entry to be `\textwidth` wide, but there is paragraph indnetation before the table, `4\tabcolsep` of cell pading around the columns and the width of the widest entry in the third column, which all needs to fit into `\textwidth`.

There is no advantage in stretching the table columns apart, it just makes it harder to read, simply use

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\centering

\noindent X\dotfill X

\noindent\begin{tabular}{llr}
\toprule
Item \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2}
Animal    & Description & Price (\$) \\
\midrule
Gnat      & per gram    & 13.65      \\
          & each        & 0.01       \\
Gnu       & stuffed     & 92.50      \\
Emu       & stuffed     & 33.33      \\
Armadillo & frozen      & 8.99       \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's just a MWE,  my actual arrays contain "long data",  that's why I am forcing the size to textwidth. Moreover,  I have more than a 50th array,  so I'd rather work with a fixed size, so the visual result is consistent.

Comment: @NNzz long entries should be in `p` columns so they wrap to a specified width, and tables with p columns naturally look consistent as they have pre-determined column widths.